# How to automatically convert underscore_identifiers into CamelCaseIdentifiers?

Tags: coding-style, naming-conventions

I have large C++ code base. It is quite inconsistent where uses underscore_identifiers and where CamelCaseIdentifiers, but is consistent within groups of files. Think about it as a smaller library merged into bigger one.

I want to standardize it within this project to [Google C++ Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml).
How can I semi-automatize it ? Preferably with Linux tools.

Comment: Are you sure it's worth it? I'd be scared of automatic tools manipulating code in a language as complex and hard to parse as C++

Comment: I also think this is somewhat ill-advised.  You'll need to have a substantial list of exceptions to protect reserved identifiers like for_each from getting camel-cased.  And what do you plan to do with strings (e.g. filenames) with embedded underscores?

Comment: There is nothing MORE ADVANCED? That could understand C++ code?

Comment: Sadly no, most c++ compilers were written in the days before tool interfaces were a concern.  Macros & templates combine to make this a very difficult problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command on the root of the source.

`find . -name "*.cpp" -exec sed 's/_\([a-zA-Z]\)\([a-zA-Z]*\)/\U\1\E\2/g' {} \;`

The output goes to STDOUT just to test it.

If you want to change the files directly you can add the `-i` option to `sed`.

**WARNING: This will change the file in place. Make a backup first!**

`find . -name "*.cpp" -exec sed -i 's/_\([a-zA-Z]\)\([a-zA-Z]*\)/\U\1\E\2/g' {} \;`

Of course you have to check all the automatic changes. See the comment from Jim Lewis.

Answer (score 0):

A simple perl script would do it. You then run it with the -i flag ("replace inplace") for all your files.

Answer (score 0):

To go from underscores to camel case (using gnu sed):

sed 's/([a-zA-Z])_([a-zA-Z])/\1\U\2/g'

And the reverse:

sed  's/([a-z])([A-Z])/\1_\L\2/g'

If you are feeling brave you can use the -i flag to work in-place.

[n.b. not tested I'm on a mac and the sed shipped with it does not support \U or \L - on gnu Linux you should be fine]